# System table to extract foreign keys in sap hana

Tags: hana

I would like to query a system-table in sap-hana db to extract information regarding foreign-keys. There are the 'Indexes' and 'Index_columns' system tables, but I only see the 'Constraint' column to contain 'Primary key' and '?' values, but not a foreign-key value. Any help regarding this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check system table REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS:

```
select * from "REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS"
```

That's where foreign keys are listed - just as it can be found in the system documentation.

Comment: Are this real foreign key constraints? Because there are nearly no entries.

Comment: Well, does the database you are using, actually have foreign keys? In SAP NetWeaver DBs, you typically won't find any of those.

Comment: It's HANA. And I exactly executed the piece of code you provided. But there is no entry with SAP_ECC.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking at an SAP ECC system? In that case, as mentioned, don't expect to find any foreign keys on the DB level. SAP doesn't implement them on DB level.

Comment: Thanks :) Do you have any references for this? I'm interested in further explanations and the reasons for this.

Comment: You won't find any SAP external documentation explaining this design decision. 
Two major reasons stand out there though: 1. the asynchronous updater process of SAP NetWeaver (read up on that, if you're not familiar) creates intermittent inconsistent database states - FK constraints would be problematic here and 2. performance. Constraint checking is very heavy on transaction throughput. Other ERP systems leave them out for the same reason (see e.g. Oracle, JDE...)